# Nginx & PHP5-fpm + CodeIgniter or Kohana = 404 error?

Tags: codeigniter, ubuntu, nginx, kohana-3, php

Ok, this is not a rewrite error because I did not touch the conf file.

I used http://www.farinspace.com/install-and-configure-nginx-server/ to make the web server.

The thing is CodeIgniter & Kohana does work on http://url.com/sub/ and http://url.com/sub/index.php

But, it does not work with http://url.com/sub/index.php/welcome or any controller (am I calling that right?), I get a 404 Not found.

Comment: I'm using sub because my file is located in a sub directory if that matters.

Comment: whats in `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` and `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`?

Comment: for both of them it says /sub/index.php

Comment: Don't use random web postings to configure Nginx when there is a well documented wiki. The `location ~ \.php$ {` config as shown on that site can get you hacked for instance. [See This Link](http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Passing_Uncontrolled_Requests_to_PHP)

Comment: thank you. I already had it change since i saw that link in a different tutorials for nginx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> am I calling that right?

Obviously not. 404 error in kohana / codeigniter means that no matching controller / action could be found. Additionally 404 error by the server means that the overall resource was not found.

Nginx requires a different server configuration than apache. [RewriteRule](http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/1505/nginx-rewrite-rule/p1) is only one example.

Comment: Check the error log of your server. Also start with a basic PHP page and just output the FCGI environment variables and compare with the FCGI/HTTP/PHP requirements of the framework(s) you're using for URL parsing.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any errors pointing towards the framework how would I output the FCGI environment variables and compare them.

Comment: okay, your problem is with nginx server configuration. Forget about the frameworks for a minute. Instead create a simple PHP file that outputs you the environment variables that nginx offers to your PHP script, like `$_SERVER` and `$_ENV`.

Comment: so I did phpinfo(); and there isnt any $_ENV But i do see all the $_SERVER variables.

Comment: It's "just" the nginx configuration. The gist is linked as well in the forum post linked in the answer (leaving that as info for any future reader of the answer).